# Where can I get an application to work with my kml files?

Tags: software-recommendation, google-earth

I have files in .kml format. In windows 7 I opened them with Google Earth, but Google earth for Linux wrongly determines the place of workout on map.

What application can I use to work with these files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can view them online with [GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/).  You load them directly with Viking GPS Analyser.

You can also convert them to GPX files using Viking or GPSBabel.  Both are available from the Ubuntu repos. See [Viking GPS Documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/viking/wikiallura/Main_Page/) for details.

Answer (score 7):

`GPSPrune` claims to support KML for read, view, edit and saving. It is java application and available for linux:

- https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpsprune/ - ubuntu's page for GPSPrune
- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GpsPrune - OSM wiki's page for GPSPrune with detailed description:

> GpsPrune is a free, open source, cross-platform program to view and edit coordinate data like GPS tracks.
>
> Viewing data with a map view using OSM maps
>
> Editing data (delete individual points or sections, variable compression, combine and rearrange data, create and edit individual points)
>
> GpsPrune can read files in the following formats: kml, including zipped and gzipped kml files and kmz files
>
> GpsPrune can also save data to files in the following formats:
>   kml and kmz files (kmz files can include photo thumbnails)

Comment: Source code: https://github.com/activityworkshop/GpsPrune

Answer (score 6):

If you're having problems with Google Earth in Ubuntu then you could try using Google Maps to view your .kml files.

As [detailed on one of the Official Google blogs](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2006/11/kml-on-google-maps.html):

> To view a KML or KMZ file on Maps, just go to [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/), and instead of searching for a geographical address like [1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, 94043](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1600%20amphitheatre%20parkway,%2094043), search for a complete Web address (including the "http://" part) of your KMZ file, like [http://kml.lover.googlepages.com/cropcircles.kmz](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://kml.lover.googlepages.com/cropcircles.kmz). Need your own web space to upload some files? Try Google Page Creator.

Google Page Creator has been shut down and Google now encourages to use [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/) instead.

Comment: I tried and it seems this option does not work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Any software reliant on [GDAL](http://gdal.org) for data input should be able to import KML files. On Ubuntu the most recommendable option is [QGIS](http://qgis.org), that supports KML seamlessly. Using the *Add Vector Layer* dialogue you can import directly a KML file for visualisation and analysis.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest to use a free conversion tool, like this one: kml2gpx.com to convert them into gpx files. It is a simple and convenient way to get the results you need.

Answer (score -1):

For even more possibilities, you can try [OSGeoLive](http://live.osgeo.org), a Xubuntu-based live DVD loaded with GIS software.

Comment: What software from OSGeoLive will work with KML files?

Comment: Please check the http://live.osgeo.org/ site to learn what applications there are that might suit your needs.