# Good specialized Xml editor for kml editing or plugin for gedit

Tags: text-editor

I frequently have to edit .kml (Google Earth) files, these can get really hard to deal with in an ordinary editor, and I need a little more than syntax highlighting, I need to be able to validate the .kml before opening in GE.

someone recommended jedit to me for this but I find it a bit sluggish and hard to configure to work properly with .kml, any recommendations? A plugin for gedit perhaps?  Maybe something for emacs, yes I use emacs too.

Comment: A great plain text editor (not only for XML) is [Atom.io](https://atom.io/) but in particular for KML files take a look to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/18530/349837).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [XML Copy Editor](http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net/), available as xmlcopyeditor from the Software Centre.

It does both syntax highlighting and document validation.